# Ignore SDCC compiler language extensions when compiling with GCC

Tags: c, gcc, sdcc

I'm trying to compile some c-code that was originally written for SDCC using GCC to run some unit tests on a host computer.
There are some language extensions for SDCC like `__xdata` or `__pdata` (for memory control) which should remain for SDCC but that should be ignored when compiled with GCC. I would strongly prefer not to modify the modules under test. Is there any way to do this?

I already figured out that it works if I add something like `#define __xdata` in the module under test. Maybe it is possible to have something like a "global definition" therefore? I have little experience with the GCC. Maybe there are compiler flags that could help me?

Answer (score 0):

There are two compiler flags, you could use:

- `-include` allows you to give a c file that is additionally included and do the defines in that file.
- Define macros via command line options `-D__xdata=`